# Need to fix autolayout issues with only UIButton's and UILabels

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, autolayout

Currently i am trying to use AutoLayout on my iOS app in xcode 6. The storyboard I am using consists of only UIButton and UILabel elements, which i would like to resize and fit based on the device. Everything works on the iphone 6 Plus and 6 but when I get to the 5S or 5 things get weird. I can't use size classes necessarily due to both 5s and 6/6P using compact width regular height. IS there a way to fix this?

all images can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tC7YR.jpg)

Comment: What are your constraints?

Comment: updated to include the image @codingchic

Answer (score 1):

Yes! With autolayout there's always a way.

From those pictures it looks like you may have a vertical constraint on the "play" button that is attached to the top of the view. Try putting that constraint on the "How Long" label. That way the button position will be relative to the title instead of the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that you have the following constraints :

1. Center all buttons and labels horizontally in the container (note,
   this is 3 different constraints you need to set).  You can select
   all 3 at once and from the Align menu center them horizontally in container.
2. Constrain How Long to Top Layout Guide (Top Space to Top Layout Guide)
3. Constrain Play to How Long (pin vertical spacing)
4. Constrain Leaderboard to Play (pin vertical spacing)
   Depending on how you want Leaderboard to float you may want to pin it to the Bottom Layout Guide instead of to play.  The buttons and labels will then move according to your constraints.